# Engineering internships as a mathematics undergraduate

Tags: mathematics, career-path, engineering, internship

I'm a second-year mathematics (pure and applied mathematics) undergraduate. In a few months time, I'll be embarking on the summer internship programme. I'm really interested in engineering (particulatly areas involving fluids and materials), and have decided to pursue a graduate degree in mechanical or computational engineering, if I can. I plan to take online courses (since I cannot take ME courses in school) in thermodynamics, mechanics and materials, CAD, etc. in order to strengthen my application. I would also like to utilize this opportunity to gain engineering experience. My question is, am I a suitable candidate for an engineering role related to my interests mentioned above? And if I am, what kind of positions can I hold, or more precisely, what kind of activities would I be likely to do?

Comment: The only way to find out is to apply. Interns are not expected to know everything, but are expected to learn quickly.

Comment: You should look at graduate curricula in the departments you're interested in, and figure out if you can pass their coursework without too much remediation..

Comment: Thank you guys.